# SQL 2016 Changing Page Verify Impact

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, checksum

Recently inherited a new SQL server and after some Blitz (Thanks Brent and team) checks have noticed that some of the DB's are set to Torn_Page or None for the page verify option.  I want to change this to Check_Sum.

Company policy is raise a change for everything which I have done, I was going to change this early morning as I am sure the impact is very low.  I understand it will flush the proc cache but will it have any other impact on a live system, should it be an out of hours change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of what you've already noted this should be a low impact change (but hey, anything could happen).

In fact, even if you change the value the checksum won't be calculated and written until the pages and written to disk - which could mean it could take days or weeks to get all of the pages actually changed in a natural lifecycle way (as in you didn't just go around rebuilding indexes to have this immediately take effect).

However, company policy is company policy. Even if there is -5% impact, if anything were to happen then the typical finger pointers will immediately throw out any relevant evidence and logic and start the blame game.

**TL;DR:** Little to no impact, I'd still put in the change control and "after hours" change due to company policy and CYA.

Comment: Cheers Sean I am on the same page I lean towards the paranoid and my place has a fun game called "BlameStorming" so anything I can do to avoid this I will, thanks for clarification.

Comment: Also consider this scenario. If your mother was going to be given A drug to save her life and she depended on this system... would you take the time to make the change request or considerate it not important. What’s important is how you treat your system...and adding a little natural nervousness IS caring for it. 